# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([64, 3])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([32, 3]))

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Reference github: [fast-bert](https://github.com/kaushaltrivedi/fast-bert)

I used to run the following notebook to predict the multi label classification using Bert model that means I don't need GPU driver instead I can use CPU memory,
here is the reference for jupyter notebook [multilabel](https://github.com/kaushaltrivedi/fast-bert/blob/master/sample_notebooks/new-toxic-multilabel.ipynb)

It's not the memory issue, How to resolve this error?

While increasing CPU with RAM size, target size also getting increasing,

> I choose n1-standard-4 (6 vCPUs, 26 GB memory) machine type.

**Sample code:**

I have removed this peace of code I use '**cpu**' instead of '**cuda**'

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    args.multi_gpu = True
else:
    args.multi_gpu = False
```

to

```
torch.device('cpu')
```

**Error Logs:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):-------------------------------------------------------------| 0.00% [0/63 00:00<00:00]
  File "bert/run.py", line 146, in <module>
    learner.fit(args.num_train_epochs, args.learning_rate, validate=True)
  File "/home/pt4_gcp/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fast_bert/learner_cls.py", line 397, in fit
    outputs = self.model(**inputs)
  File "/home/pt4_gcp/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pt4_gcp/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fast_bert/modeling.py", line 205, in forward
    logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1, self.num_labels)
  File "/home/pt4_gcp/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pt4_gcp/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 617, in forward
    reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/home/pt4_gcp/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2433, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
    raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([64, 3])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([32, 3]))
```

Comment: @cronoik can you check with the updated question

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a different number of instances for input [32] and target [64]. Please make sure that you have same number of target variables as the number of inputs.

Comment: how to define target size

Comment: You don't have to. Say, you have X,y where X is the training data and y is the target. Then both should have same number of data items.